# jQuery number overwrite after click

Tags: jquery

How can I overwrite the original number without create a new "var"?
I would like that if I every time click "more", after add plus 10 for the original number.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
<div id="more">more</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var count = 10;

    $('#more').click(function(){
        var count = count + 10;
    ));

    $('#result').html(count);

});

</script>
```

Comment: Just remove the var in the click function

Comment: Do you want the displayed value to start at 0 or 10?

Comment: I tried, but not working. :(

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I would like to start at 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0; 
    $('#more').click(function() {
        count += 10; // add 10 to outer var `count`
        $('#result').html(count); // display new value
    }).trigger('click'); // initialize to 10 by triggering a 'click'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var count = count + 10;
```

Which means that you are creating a new count each time. Just update the old one.

```
 count = count + 10;
```

That will fix it

or even simpler

```
count += 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the var in the click function. With the `var` in the click function you would create a new variable everytime

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var count = 10;

    $('#more').click(function(){
        count = count + 10;
        $('#result').html(count);
    ));
});
```